# navController not updating locations in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have built NavigationRail for my news app that lets me navigate to the search screen and home screen. I am having a problem that the NavController that I passed to my NavigationRail is not giving me an updated current position due to which my navigationRail Icons are not showing that they are selected when at a destination.

[image]

Code for my Navigation Rail is:

```
@Composable
fun NewsNavigationRail(
    navController: NavHostController
){

    val navigationItems = Destinations.values()

    NavigationRail{
        navigationItems.filter{
            it.icon != null && it.label != null
        }.forEach {
            NavigationRailItem(
                icon = { Icon(
                    it.icon!!,
                    contentDescription = it.name
                ) },


// problematic line --------------------------
                selected = navController.currentDestination?.route == it.route,
                onClick = {

                },
                label = { Text(it.label!!) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And code for my NavigationHost is:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun NavigationHost(){

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Row {
        NewsNavigationRail(
            navController = navController
        )

        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Destinations.HomeScreen.route){
            composable(Destinations.HomeScreen.route){
                val newsViewModel = hiltViewModel<NewsViewModel>()
                HomeScreen(newsViewModel, navController)
            }
            composable(
                "${Destinations.NewsScreen.route}/{url}",
                arguments = listOf(navArgument("url"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
                })
            ){
                val url = it.arguments?.getString("url")
                NewsScreen(url)
            }
            composable(Destinations.SearchScreen.route){
                val newsViewModel = hiltViewModel<NewsViewModel>()
                SearchScreen()
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you navigate between screens? Maybe problem is the icon ripple effect?

Comment: Yes I can move between screens.

Comment: Can u change  unselectedContentColor and  selectedContentColor in  NavigationRail

Comment: I have tried but it isn't working

Comment: Can u post Destination’s class, i suspect, you have arguments in news screen that may affect the name, did you try without argument

Comment: And, can u get current route with this code;  val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you so much man, this was bugging me for days!!

Comment: Well done! can u accept my answer. i'm adding as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState() 
val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
```